# building custom navigation in razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I hope to get some useful input on how to implement my desired functionality:

I've got a razor partial view without a model that contains the navigation for my webapp. As some functions are only ment to be available for specific users, I want to customize the view.

In particular I want to show/not show specific *li* elements in the *ul*.
I already have a query which determines whether the element needs to be shown or not.
The element itself has to be like this:

```
<li><a href='@Url.Action("Index", "Controller", new {area = ""})' onclick="">@Resources.Label1</a></li>
```

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the ViewBag.

Main view or controller:

```
ViewBag.LoggedIn = true;
```

Partial view:

```
<ul>
    <li>Visible to everyone</li>

    @if (ViewBag.LoggedIn == true) {
        <li>Visibility based on some data</li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: As I said the containing view is not bound to a model... And I don't really want to change that.

Comment: I think this works for me.. I really tryed to load some html markup into the partial view which seems to be the wrong approach..